# Reason for "object has no attribute" in this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, methods

I am trying to write a class function for an arbitrary modulo class under Sum and product, etc.. operations.

I wrote similar ones for the complex numbers and areas of shapes.

However, here I am confused because I am not sure if I should return the remainder class  after each "method" and if I need a repr function at the end?

This is the code:

```
class ModuloZ(object):
    def __init__(self,modulo,number):

        self.modulo = modulo
        self.number = number

    def __add__(self,b):
        Sum = self.number + b.number
        return self.Sum % self.modulo

    def __sub__ (self,b):
        Remainder = self.number - b.number
        return self.Remainder % self.modulo

    def __mul__(self,b):
        Product = self.number * b.number
        return self.Product % self.modulo
```

I always get for e.g. `ModuloZ` object has no attribute `Product` when I try to print the following:

```
a = ModuloZ(7, 9)
b = ModuloZ(7, 12)
print a *b
```

expected to get :
    3

So, my main question is why I do I get this when I clearly defined the product operation, or that doesn't work with this type of input.

I apologize if the mistake is very small or basic, but I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Why are you using `self` there? As the error says, you haven't defined anything called `self.Product`, just `Product`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__mul__` method, you assign a value to `Product`, but you don't assign any value to `self.Product`, which you try and use in the next line.

Similarly for your other methods.

Comment: Thank you a lot! you have no idea how much time I wasted on this thing.